# How to give create/alter stage privileges to a role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have given `grant all privileges to role svn_dev`, but it is not giving access to create, alter and drop stage permissions across all schemas. How do I provide this to a role?

I have also tried

```
grant ownership on database DA_DEV to role svn_dev;
```

I get an error

> SQL execution error: Dependent grant of privilege 'CREATE SCHEMA' on securable.
>
> To revoke all dependent grants while transferring object ownership, use convenience command 'GRANT OWNERSHIP ON <target_objects> TO <target_role> REVOKE CURRENT GRANTS'.

How to give create stage permissions?

Comment: The error message tells you how to resolve the issue. Did you actually read the words in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives a way to fix it in most cases. Try this:

```
grant ownership on database DA_DEV to role svn_dev revoke current grants;
```

If you can't revoke current grants because it would be too much work to re-issue the grants, you can explicitly revoke the grants that are preventing a change in ownership. You can check them using `show grants`.

You can grant create stage like this:

```
grant create stage on schema <DATABASE>.<SCHEMA> to role <ROLE>;
```

Comment: Is giving ownership the only method for create stage privileges?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to grant create stage.